# How to use node_modules on Github Pages, without uploading to repo

Tags: github, npm, jekyll, github-pages, node-modules

I'm hosting a site on *Github pages*, and using Jekyll to generate it.

I added Angular and Lodash to my project using `npm`, but didn't want to upload 200 odd files to GitHub so I added `node_modules` to my `.gitignore` file and just made sure they were added as dependencies within `package.json`. The problem then becomes that GitHub pages/Jekyll doesn't auto-install the packages when it (Jekyll) generates.

So my question is, how can I use NPM on GitHub pages without actually uploading my node_modules folder into my GitHub repository?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

## build your site locally

Just generate your static files locally and then upload the final website to Github pages (Github can host non Jekyll websites)

## use CI

Implement a script that after uploading your files to the master branch (in Travies for example), it builds your site and push the changes to the gp-pages branch.

Answer (score 2):

According to the GitHub, you can add a _config.yml file to tell Jekyll to "include" the "node_modules" and "vendors" directories.

See:
https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-jekyll

Comment: I see no mention of anything to do with this, or even any mention of `node_modules` on that page.

Comment: If you followed the link, you saw the statement: _By default, Jekyll doesn't build files or folders that: are located in a folder called /node_modules or /vendor_. So, you need to use the includes and add the node_modules folder.

Comment: Does this actually build the node modules though? Because OP didn't want to actually add it to the repo.